# Postgres query over ODBC a order of magnitude slower?

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql, odbc

We have an application which gets some data from a PostgreSQL 9.0.3 database through the psqlodbc 09.00.0200 driver in the following way:

1) SQLExecDirect with `START TRANSACTION`
2) SQLExecDirect with

```
DECLARE foo SCROLL CURSOR FOR  
SELECT table.alotofcolumns  
FROM table  
ORDER BY name2, id LIMIT 10000
```

3) SQLPrepare with

```
SELECT table.alotofcolumns, l01.languagedescription
FROM fetchcur('foo', ?, ?) table (column definitions) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN languagetable l01 ON (l01.lang = 'EN'
                                  AND l01.type = 'some type'
                                  AND l01.grp  = 'some group'
                                  AND l01.key  = table.somecolumn)
[~20 more LEFT OUTER JOINS in the same style, but for an other column]
```

4) SQLExecute with param1 set to SQL_FETCH_RELATIVE and param2 set to 1
5) SQLExecute with param1 set to SQL_FETCH_RELATIVE and param2 set to -1
6) SQLExecute with param1 set to SQL_FETCH_RELATIVE and param2 set to 0
7) deallocate all, close cursor, end transaction

The function fetchcur executes `FETCH RELATIVE $3 IN $1 INTO rec` where rec is a record and returns that record. Step 4-6 are executed again and again on user request and there are a lot more querys executed in this transaction in the meantime. It can also take quite some time before another user request is made. Usually the querys takes that long:

4) ~ 130 ms
5) ~ 115 ms
6) ~ 110 ms

This is normally too slow for a fast user experience. So i tried the same statements from psql command line with \timing on. For step 3-6 i used that statements:

3)

```
PREPARE p_foo (INTEGER, INTEGER) AS 
SELECT table.alotofcolumns, l01.languagedescription
FROM fetchcur('foo', $1, $2) table (column definitions) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN languagetable l01 ON (l01.lang = 'EN'
                                  AND l01.type = 'some type'
                                  AND l01.grp  = 'some group'
                                  AND l01.key  = table.somecolumn)
[~20 more LEFT OUTER JOINS in the same style, but for an other column]
```

4-6)

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE EXECUTE p_foo (6, x);
```

For the first EXECUTE it took 89 ms, but then it went down to ~7 ms. Even if i wait several minutes between the executes it stays at under 10 ms per query. So where could the additional 100 ms be gone? The application and database are on the same system, so network delay shouldn't be an issue. Each LEFT OUTER JOIN only returns one row and only one column of that result is added to the result set. So the result is one row with ~200 columns mostly of type VARCHAR and INTEGER. But that shouldn't be so much data to take around 100 ms to transfer on the same machine. So any hints would be helpful.

The machine has 2 GB of RAM and parameters are set to:

```
shared_buffers = 512MB
effective_cache_size = 256MB
work_mem = 16MB
maintenance_work_mem = 256MB
temp_buffers = 8MB
wal_buffers= 1MB
```

EDIT: I just found out how to create a mylog from psqlodbc, but i can't find timing values in there.

EDIT2: Also could add a timestamp to every line. This really shows that it takes >100ms until a respond is received by the psqlodbc driver. So i tried again with `psql` and added the option `-h 127.0.0.1` to make sure it also goes over TCP/IP. The result with `psql` is <10ms. How is this possible?

```
00:07:51.026 [3086550720][SQLExecute]
00:07:51.026 [3086550720]PGAPI_Execute: entering...1
00:07:51.026 [3086550720]PGAPI_Execute: clear errors...
00:07:51.026 [3086550720]prepareParameters was not called, prepare state:3
00:07:51.026 [3086550720]SC_recycle_statement: self= 0x943b1e8
00:07:51.026 [3086550720]PDATA_free_params:  ENTER, self=0x943b38c
00:07:51.026 [3086550720]PDATA_free_params:  EXIT
00:07:51.026 [3086550720]Exec_with_parameters_resolved: copying statement params: trans_status=6, len=10128, stmt='SELECT [..]'
00:07:51.026 [3086550720]ResolveOneParam: from(fcType)=-15, to(fSqlType)=4(23)
00:07:51.026 [3086550720]cvt_null_date_string=0 pgtype=23 buf=(nil)
00:07:51.026 [3086550720]ResolveOneParam: from(fcType)=4, to(fSqlType)=4(23)
00:07:51.026 [3086550720]cvt_null_date_string=0 pgtype=23 buf=(nil)
00:07:51.026 [3086550720]   stmt_with_params = 'SELECT [..]'
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]about to begin SC_execute
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]       Sending SELECT statement on stmt=0x943b1e8, cursor_name='SQL_CUR0x943b1e8' qflag=0,1
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]CC_send_query: conn=0x9424668, query='SELECT [..]'
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]CC_send_query: conn=0x9424668, query='SAVEPOINT _EXEC_SVP_0x943b1e8'
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]send_query: done sending query 35bytes flushed
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]in QR_Constructor
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]exit QR_Constructor
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]read 21, global_socket_buffersize=4096
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]send_query: got id = 'C'
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]send_query: ok - 'C' - SAVEPOINT
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]send_query: setting cmdbuffer = 'SAVEPOINT'
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]send_query: returning res = 0x8781c90
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]send_query: got id = 'Z'
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]QResult: enter DESTRUCTOR
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]QResult: in QR_close_result
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]QResult: free memory in, fcount=0
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]QResult: free memory out
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]QResult: enter DESTRUCTOR
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]QResult: exit close_result
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]QResult: exit DESTRUCTOR
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]send_query: done sending query 1942bytes flushed
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]in QR_Constructor
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]exit QR_Constructor
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]read -1, global_socket_buffersize=4096
00:07:51.027 [3086550720]Lasterror=11
00:07:51.133 [3086550720]!!!  poll ret=1 revents=1
00:07:51.133 [3086550720]read 4096, global_socket_buffersize=4096
00:07:51.133 [3086550720]send_query: got id = 'T'
00:07:51.133 [3086550720]QR_fetch_tuples: cursor = '', self->cursor=(nil)
00:07:51.133 [3086550720]num_fields = 166
00:07:51.133 [3086550720]READING ATTTYPMOD
00:07:51.133 [3086550720]CI_read_fields: fieldname='id', adtid=23, adtsize=4, atttypmod=-1 (rel,att)=(0,0)
[last two lines repeated for the other columns]
00:07:51.138 [3086550720]QR_fetch_tuples: past CI_read_fields: num_fields = 166
00:07:51.138 [3086550720]MALLOC: tuple_size = 100, size = 132800
00:07:51.138 [3086550720]QR_next_tuple: inTuples = true, falling through: fcount = 0, fetch_number = 0
00:07:51.139 [3086550720]qresult: len=3, buffer='282'
[last line repeated for the other columns]
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]end of tuple list -- setting inUse to false: this = 0x87807e8 SELECT 1
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]_QR_next_tuple: 'C' fetch_total = 1 & this_fetch = 1
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]QR_next_tuple: backend_rows < CACHE_SIZE: brows = 0, cache_size = 0
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]QR_next_tuple: reached eof now
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]send_query: got id = 'Z'
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]     done sending the query:
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]extend_column_bindings: entering ... self=0x943b270, bindings_allocated=166, num_columns=166
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]exit extend_column_bindings=0x9469500
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]SC_set_Result(943b1e8, 87807e8)
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]QResult: enter DESTRUCTOR
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]retval=0
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]CC_send_query: conn=0x9424668, query='RELEASE _EXEC_SVP_0x943b1e8'
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]send_query: done sending query 33bytes flushed
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]in QR_Constructor
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]exit QR_Constructor
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]read -1, global_socket_buffersize=4096
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]Lasterror=11
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]!!!  poll ret=1 revents=1
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]read 19, global_socket_buffersize=4096
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]send_query: got id = 'C'
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]send_query: ok - 'C' - RELEASE
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]send_query: setting cmdbuffer = 'RELEASE'
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]send_query: returning res = 0x877cd30
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]send_query: got id = 'Z'
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]QResult: enter DESTRUCTOR
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]QResult: in QR_close_result
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]QResult: free memory in, fcount=0
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]QResult: free memory out
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]QResult: enter DESTRUCTOR
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]QResult: exit close_result
00:07:51.140 [3086550720]QResult: exit DESTRUCTOR
```

EDIT3: I realized i didn't used the same query from the mylog in the `psql` test before. It seems `psqlodbc` doesn't use a `PREPARE` for SQLPrepare and SQLExecute. It adds the param value and send the query. As araqnid suggested i set the `log_duration` param to 0 and compared the results from postgresql log with that from the app and psql. The result are as follows:

```
                            psql/app     pglog
query executed from app:      110 ms     70 ms
psql with PREPARE/EXECUTE:     10 ms      5 ms
psql with full SELECT:         85 ms     70 ms
```

So how to interpret that values? It seems the most time is spend sending the full query to the database (10000 chars) and generating a execution plan. If that is true changing the calls to SQLPrepare and SQLExecute to explicit PREPARE/EXECUTE statements executed over SQLExecDirect could solve the problem. Any objections?

Comment: "00:07:51.133 [3086550720]!!!  poll ret=1 revents=1" - did you add the exclamation marks to highlight this line or are they part of the output? Just above, it sent a savepoint command and got a response back double-quick so it doesn't seem to be network lag. Although it seems to be getting a bigger chunk of data back for the actual query result, which isn't surprising...

Comment: something else to try- set `log_duration` for that database user and see if postgresql on the server side logs that query as taking longer when you run it from your server compared to running it directly with psql.

Comment: The exclamation marks are part of the output, i didn't add them. `psqlodbc` can also be recompiled with the option to use `select()` instead of `poll()`. Tried that without any difference. Thanks for the hint with `log_duration`. I'll try that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the problem and it was that psqlodbc's SQLPrepare/SQLExecute by default doesn't execute a PREPARE/EXECUTE. The driver itself builds the SELECT and sends that.

The solution is to add `UseServerSidePrepare=1` to the odbc.ini or to the ConnectionString for SQLDriverConnect. The total execution time for one query measured from the application dropped from >100ms to 5-10ms.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the timing between psql and your program are comparable.

Maybe I'm missing something, but in psql you are only preparing the statements, but never really fetching the data. EXPLAIN PLAN is not sending data either

So the time difference is most probably the network traffic that is needed to send all rows from the server to the client.

The only way to reduce this time is to either get a faster network or to select fewer columns. Do you really need all the columns that are included in *"alotofcolumns"*?

Comment: The `ANALYZE` part of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` does really execute the query. I tried the query again without `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to verify and except the first query it is close to the results before and under 10 ms. In our case the client and server are on the same machine. So there is only the network stack from the localhost between them. That shouldn't add up that much time or did i miss something? I still think it would be more costly to execute another query later if there is a missing column detected. And its only one row. I don't think there is more than at most some KB of data in that columns

Comment: You are right `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` does run the query but it does not send the results to the client. And if the amount of data sent is large (many rows, large column data) then this can still take a substantial amount of time (memory needs to be allocated on both sides, data needs to be pushed through various software layers and so on).